# Personality insight input var nodejs

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, personality-insights

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var cfenv = require("cfenv");

var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

http.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind);

var PersonalityInsightsV2 = require('watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights/v2');

var personality_insights = new PersonalityInsightsV2({
  username: '<YOUR-USERNAME>',
  password: '<YOUR-PASSWORD>'
});

personality_insights.profile({
  text: "<YOUR-100-UNIQUE-WORDS>",
  language: 'en' },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err)
      console.log('error:', err);
    else
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
});
```

I created these two files the above index.js and package.json

```
    {
  "name": "myWatsonApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Watson Personality Insights application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cfenv": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "watson-developer-cloud": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

when I run npm start I gives me this error  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should include the files in my main system to the folder that I run.Thats how I solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

Make sure the dependencies are installed

```
npm install
```

Make sure there is an `index.js` file in the root directory otherwise, update the start script to point to your main js file

Start your application using `npm start`